# Submitting a form inside a detail view creates a new object instead of replacing it

Tags: django

I’m trying to create a dashboard for the staff users to fill in and edit some information regarding their users. The form works and saves successfully, but when I submit it for a second time, it creates a new object. It won’t replace the previous:

This is my *views.py* file:

```
class ScientificInfoView(FormMixin, DetailView):
    model = ScientificInfo
    template_name = 'reg/scientific-info.html'
    form_class = ScientificInfoForm

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('scientific-info', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})

    def get_context_date(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ScientificInfoView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = ScientificInfoForm()
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        return super(ScientificInfoView, self).form_valid(form)
```

And my template:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{% url 'scientific-info' pk=object.id %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form}}
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

File *urls.py*:

```
path('surveys/scientific/<pk>', login_required(views.ScientificInfoView.as_view()), name='scientific-info')
```

I’m pretty sure that the action part in my form is causing the issue, but how can I solve it?

Comment: Could you share your `urls.py`? Your `reverse` call probably doesn't match the URL conf for your view.

Comment: there, I added urls

Comment: Thanks. Looking at this again, I see the problem here is that `self.object.id`in `ScientificInfoView.get_success_url` is `None` or an empty string.

Comment: Is there a reason the `ScientificInfo` model instance may not have an `id` at the point that the `ScientificInfoView` succeeds? Maybe adding the declaration of `ScientificInfoForm` would help make this clear...

Comment: I edited some things in my view. now the form gets saved and redirects just fine. however, it creates a new object. it wont replace the previous one. could you take a look at the edits? thanks

Comment: I'm confused. Is the ReverseMatch error fixed now?

Comment: yes I fixed that issue

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
def get_success_url(self):
    pk = self.kwargs["pk"]
    return reverse("scientific-info", kwargs={"pk": pk})
```

Or

```
class ScientificInfoView(FormMixin, DetailView):
    model = ScientificInfo
    template_name = 'reg/scientific-info.html'
    form_class = ScientificInfoForm
    def get_success_url(self):
         return reverse("scientific-info", args=[pk]) # You can replace pk
```

Comment: I did this but I still have the same error